# Crosstab Excel - match with multiple criteria and return multiple values to one cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to return a combined value in a crosstab in excel.
Example of the crosstab:

[image]

I want to make a formula that puts the number together for the criteria Unknown and Acc1 meaning 70+80 = 150. So I want 1 formula in a single cell to return 150. But the issue is that Unknown and Acc1 might switch spots when I download data, so it has to be dynamic for column A and row 1.
I have tried to Xlookup this and manage to find 70 but not a formula that returned 150.

This also means that I can't have a formula that wants to find the sum of column B, as this might be called Acc2 next month.

Hopes this makes sense.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Try using <kbd>SUMPRODUCT( )</kbd> or <kbd>SUM( )</kbd>

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>B6</kbd>

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(A2:A4="Unknown")*(B1:D1="Acc1")*B2:D4)
```

---

You could try the following as well:

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>F3</kbd>

```
=LET(
     _lastCol, MATCH(2,1/(1:1<>"")),
     _criteriaOne, B1:INDEX(1:1,,_lastCol)="Acc1",
     _lastRow, MATCH(2,1/(A:A<>"")),
     _criteriaTwo, A2:INDEX(A:A,_lastRow)="Unknown",
     _data, B2:INDEX(B:ZZ,_lastRow,_lastCol),
     _answer, SUM(IFERROR(--(_criteriaOne)*--(_criteriaTwo)*_data,0)),
     _answer)
```

---

Or,

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>F2</kbd>

```
=LET(
     a, A:E,
     b, FILTER(a,BYROW(a,LAMBDA(r,COUNTA(r)>0))),
     c, TOROW(TAKE(a,1),3),
     d, TOCOL(TAKE(a,,1),3),
     e, DROP(a,1,1),
     f, WRAPROWS(TOCOL(e,1),COLUMNS(c)),
     SUM(--("Unknown"=d)*--("Acc1"=c)*f))
```

---

Comment: To get a better understanding what does "--" mean?

And is it possible to just mark column A (so it is A:A) and row 1 (1:1) so it still works?

Comment: Nice use of SUMPRODUCT and double unary operator. Upvoted!

Comment: @JBerggreen `--` means double unary operator, which coerces the `TRUE` and `FALSE`s to 1 and 0. Also why do you want to include all the rows and columns, excel will run out of memory quickly and let the excel slow down, that is a very bad practice.

Comment: Ahh makes sense. Because every month I will be collecting new data, and I am never sure of how many new rows or columns there is and they might switch spot. So I need to have it as dynamic as possible

Comment: @JBerggreen what is your excel version may i know here

Comment: Version 2307 32-bit

Comment: Try the following formula: `=LET(
         _lastCol, MATCH(2,1/(1:1<>"")),
         _criteriaOne, B1:INDEX(1:1,,_lastCol)="Acc1",
         _lastRow, MATCH(2,1/(1:1<>"")),
         _criteriaTwo, A2:INDEX(A:A,_lastRow)="Unknown",
         _data, B2:INDEX(B:L,_lastRow,_lastCol),
         _answer, SUM(IFERROR(--(_criteriaOne)*--(_criteriaTwo)*_data,0)),
         _answer)`

Comment: @JBerggreen looks like you are in `LTSC Excel 2021` Version, have you tried the formula?

Comment: I just got an error that says "The first argument of LET must be a valid name".

Comment: Not sure why you are getting that error, it works on my end, can you change the variables with some other names and try